# Rails Tutorial 11章 herokuにデプロイできません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Rails Tutorialの11章を進めています。
11章最後にgit push herokuコマンドを実行すると以下のエラーが出ます。

SendGridのアカウント凍結が原因かと思いましたが、アカウントが有効になっても同じエラーが出ます。
SendGridのAPI Keyは設定しました。

同様の現象を見たことがある方がいらっしゃいましたら、助言をいただけるとありがたいです。

コンソールのログ

> Enumerating objects: 85, done. Counting objects: 100% (85/85), done.
> Delta compression using up to 8 threads Compressing objects: 100%
> (51/51), done. Writing objects: 100% (52/52), 9.37 KiB | 1.34 MiB/s,
> done. Total 52 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: Compressing
> source files... done. remote: Building source: remote:  remote: ----->
> Ruby app detected remote: -----> Installing bundler 1.17.3 remote:
> -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.5 remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.17.3
> remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test
> --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any
> of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for
> ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32,
> x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`. remote:
> Using rake 13.0.1 remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.6 remote:
> Using i18n 0.9.5 remote:        Using minitest 5.10.3 remote:
> Using thread_safe 0.3.6 remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.7 remote:
> Using activesupport 5.1.6 remote:        Using builder 3.2.4 remote:
> Using erubi 1.9.0 remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.4.0 remote:
> Using nokogiri 1.10.9 remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
> remote:        Using crass 1.0.6 remote:        Using loofah 2.5.0
> remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0 remote:        Using
> actionview 5.1.6 remote:        Using rack 2.2.2 remote:        Using
> rack-test 1.1.0 remote:        Using actionpack 5.1.6 remote:
> Using nio4r 2.5.2 remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
> remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.6.5 remote:        Using
> actioncable 5.1.6 remote:        Using globalid 0.4.2 remote:
> Using activejob 5.1.6 remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.2 remote:
> Using mail 2.7.1 remote:        Using actionmailer 5.1.6 remote:
> Using activemodel 5.1.6 remote:        Using arel 8.0.0 remote:
> Using activerecord 5.1.6 remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0 remote:
> Using autoprefixer-rails 9.7.6 remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.12
> remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.4 remote:        Using ffi 1.13.1
> remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.10.1 remote:        Using
> sass-listen 4.0.0 remote:        Using sass 3.7.4 remote:        Using
> bootstrap-sass 3.3.7 remote:        Using will_paginate 3.1.6 remote:
> Using bootstrap-will_paginate 1.0.0 remote:        Using bundler
> 1.17.3 remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2 remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1 remote:        Using method_source 1.0.0
> remote:        Using thor 1.0.1 remote:        Using railties 5.1.6
> remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2 remote:        Using faker
> 1.7.3 remote:        Using multi_json 1.14.1 remote:        Using jbuilder 2.7.0 remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.3.1 remote:
> Using pg 0.20.0 remote:        Using puma 3.9.1 remote:        Using
> sprockets 3.7.2 remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1 remote:
> Using rails 5.1.6 remote:        Using tilt 2.0.10 remote:
> Using sass-rails 5.0.6 remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
> remote:        Using turbolinks 5.0.1 remote:        Using uglifier
> 3.2.0 remote:        Bundle complete! 26 Gemfile dependencies, 63 gems now installed remote:        Gems in the groups development and test
> were not installed. remote:        Bundled gems are installed into
> `./vendor/bundle` remote:        Bundle completed (0.46s) remote:
> Cleaning up the bundler cache. remote:        The dependency
> tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is
> installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is
> only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those
> platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`. remote: -----> Installing
> node-v12.16.2-linux-x64 remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks remote:
> -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile remote:        rake aborted! remote:
> ***> SyntaxError: /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/config/environments/production.rb:73:
>
> syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '}' remote:
>
> :port         =>'587' remote:            ^ remote:
>
> /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/config/environments/production.rb:74: syntax
>
> error, unexpected =>, expecting end-of-input remote:
>
> :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'], remote:
>
> ^~ remote:***
> /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require' remote:        /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in` block in require' remote:
> /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency' remote:        /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in` require' remote:
> /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in
> `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>' remote:        /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in` each' remote:
> /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in
> `block in <class:Engine>' remote:        /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in` instance_exec' remote:
> /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
> `run' remote:        /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in` block in run_initializers' remote:
> /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in
> `each' remote:        /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in` tsort_each_child' remote:
> /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in
> `run_initializers' remote:        /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in` initialize!' remote:
> /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>' remote:        /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in` require' remote:
> /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in
> `require_environment!' remote:        /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:445:in` block in run_tasks_blocks' remote:
> /tmp/build_e0d5d49b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in
> `block (2 levels) in define' remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
> remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace) remote:
> remote:  ! remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed. remote:  !
> remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app. remote:
> remote:  !     Push failed remote: Verifying deploy... remote:
> remote: !       Push rejected to fast-depths-48015. remote:  To
> https://git.heroku.com/***********.git  ! [remote rejected]
> master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push
> some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/***********.git'

斜線の部分からproduction.rbの変更部分が原因かと推測していますが、何度見返しても書き損じはありません。
production.rbの変更部分

> config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
> config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
> host => '***********.herokuapp.com'
> config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
> ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
> :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
> :port => '587',
> :authentication => :plain,
> :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
> :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
> :domain => 'heroku.com',
> :enable_starttls_auto => true   }

開発環境
ruby 2.6.5p114
Rails 5.1.6
VSCode
WSL:Debian

本番環境
Heroku

【追記】production.rbのコードを全文貼り付けます。コメントを残しているので長くなってしまってすみません。

> Rails.application.configure do   # Settings specified here will take
> precedence over those in config/application.rb.
>
> ## Code is not reloaded between requests.   config.cache_classes =
>
> true
>
> ## Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
>
> your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers   # and
> those relying on copy on write to perform better.   # Rake tasks
> automatically ignore this option for performance.   config.eager_load
> = true
>
> ## Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
>
> config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
> config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
>
> ## Attempt to read encrypted secrets from `config/secrets.yml.enc`.
>
> ## Requires an encryption key in `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` or   # `config/secrets.yml.key`.   config.read_encrypted_secrets = true
>
> ## Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default
>
> since   # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
> config.public_file_server.enabled =
> ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
>
> ## Compress JavaScripts and CSS.   config.assets.js_compressor =
>
> :uglifier   # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
>
> ## Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is
>
> missed.   config.assets.compile = false
>
> ## `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved
>
> to config/initializers/assets.rb
>
> ## Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an
>
> asset server.   # config.action_controller.asset_host =
> 'http://assets.example.com'
>
> ## Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
>
> config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
>
> ## config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX
>
> ## Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
>
> config.action_cable.mount_path = nil   # config.action_cable.url =
> 'wss://example.com/cable'   #
> config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com',
> /http://example.*/ ]
>
> ## Force all access to the app over SSL, use
>
> Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.   config.force_ssl
> = true
>
> ## Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic
>
> information   # when problems arise.   config.log_level = :debug
>
> ## Prepend all log lines with the following tags.   config.log_tags =
>
> [ :request_id ]
>
> ## Use a different cache store in production.   # config.cache_store
>
> = :mem_cache_store
>
> ## Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per
>
> environment)   # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque   #
> config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "sample_app_#{Rails.env}"
> config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
>
> ## Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
>
> ## Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
>
> config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
> config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp   host =
> '***********.herokuapp.com'
> config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
> ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
> :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
> :port           => '587',
> :authentication => :plain,
> :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
> :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
> :domain         => 'heroku.com',
> :enable_starttls_auto => true   }
>
> ## Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale
>
> fall back to   # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be
> found).   config.i18n.fallbacks = true
>
> ## Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
>
> config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
>
> ## Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not
>
> suppressed.   config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
>
> ## Use a different logger for distributed setups.   # require
>
> 'syslog/logger'   # config.logger =
> ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')
>
> if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
> logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
> logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
> config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)   end
>
> ## Do not dump schema after migrations.
>
> config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false end

Comment: production.rb の内容は公開可能ですか?

Comment: 本文人追記しました。読みづらくて申し訳ありません

Comment: 原因は不明のままですが、解決しました。
回答をくださった方ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby -cW production.rb
```

とするともう少し原因を絞れるかもしれません。(コメントに書くべきだと思いますが、まだ書けないのでこちらでご容赦ください)

Comment: ruby -cw config/environments/production.rbを実行したところ、
Syntax OK　と表示されるのみで特に詳しい情報は出てきませんでした。
ruby -cWとはどういうコマンドなのでしょう？検索の仕方が悪いのか情報が見つかりませんでした…

Comment: ruby --help　を実行するとオプションの意味が出てきます。-cはcheck syntax only、-Wはset warning level; 0=silence, 1=medium, 2=verbose　です。